# Struts 2 + Spring and contextConfigLocation

Tags: spring, struts2, web.xml

I am trying to integrate and configure Struts 2 + Spring and register ContextLoaderListener listener class as  parameter contextConfigLocation I am trying to write SpringBeans.xml instead of the default applicationContext.xml. But the problem is that this SpringBeans.xml located right at the root src directory.. and I am not shure how to write param-value.. /src/SpringBeans.xml ...help please..

Comment: what is the problem and post spring config.

Answer (score 0):

You *wouldn't* write `src/SpringBeans.xml`, because your source directory isn't a deployable artifact.

You should put the config file either:

- On the classpath (IMO generally preferable)
- In WEB-INF (to prevent direct client access)

If it's on the classpath, how to get it deployed depends on your build/packaging system.

For example, in Eclipse, you can just leave it at the root of `src`. If you're using Maven, it should go at the root of `src/main/resources`. If it's not at the root, modify the below accordingly.

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>classpath:SpringBeans.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Otherwise provide the app-relative path, e.g.,

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/META-INF/SpringBeans.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

(Or in `WEB-INF`, or wherever you're putting it.)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code,

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>Example</display-name>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/classes/SpringBeans.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

if you are using placing your SpringBeans.xml in src and you are using ANt build then it will be placed to WEB-INF/classes folder. But you are placing in another folder say /config then you have write you build.xml to place *.xml files to WEB-INF/classes folder when deploying.